# Can the set L, of all even polynomials be a subspace of F[X]?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

So I have the question Let F be a field and let L be the set of all polynomials f(x) element of F[X] satisfying the condition that deg(f) is even. Is L a subspace of F[X]?

I would say that L is not a subspace of F[X].

Taking the condition f(-a)=-f(a)

if we took f(x)=x^2 -2, which has an even degree, then

f(-a)=(-a)^2 -2 = a^2 -2 which does not equal -(x^2 -2)

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Where did the condition $f(-a)=-f(a)$ come from?  That's what it means for the polynomial $f$ to be an odd function, but actually being an even function ($f(-x)=f(x)$) isn't the same as having even degree.

Comment: You need to distinguish between the concepts of *even degree* and *even* as a function; the former means the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ is divisible by $2$; that latter means $f(-a) = f(a)$ for any $a \in F$.

Comment: @NateEldredge:  whoops!  Corrected!  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @RobertLewis, thank you, yes I understand the difference now, silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even degree polynomial is NOT the same as even function. For example: $x^2+x$ is an even degree polynomial but not an even function. So if your set $L$ has even degree polynomials then it is NOT a subspace because $f(x)=x^2+x$ and $g(x)=-x^2$ are both in $L$ but $f+g \not\in L$.